# Shell script cannot call some commands when starting up Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a set of shell scripts at login on a virtual install of Ubuntu 16.04.

I have added the shell scripts in ~/.bashrc and they load just fine, most of the script just run a few terminal commands, but one them calls in other programs – this script is the problem, it fails to see the program as installed "command not found".

When I run the same script from command line it works just fine.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember, your shell environment isn't fully set until the bash run-control (bashrc) script has finished. It sounds like the "one that calls in other problems" attempts to run before the PATH allowing the programs to be found has been set.

Comment: This is a valuable insight, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Note also that `~/.bashrc` is invoked during setup of **interactive** shells. It isn't called while noninteractive scripts are started, and scripts that depend on it are arguably buggy. (It's unwise to source dotfiles from scripts because those dotfiles are expected to change as user preferences do; someone changing their interactive shell's setup shouldn't have to think about what the impact of that change will be on their scripts).

Comment: (On a related note `.bashrc` usually _isn't_ used to set the PATH -- best practice is to do that in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` instead, which runs only on login shells and not all interactive shells; the difference is that one often starts several interactive shells as children of a single login shell, so appending to the PATH in your `.bashrc` can sometimes cause PATH elements to be duplicated).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, my script was running before PATH was set. Adding the required PATH to the script allows it to run.

`PATH = $PATH:<my_path>`

Comment: That command isn't valid -- it doesn't work when you have spaces around the `=`